# How do you make login query for every api call and how to handle response with rxjava?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

So I'm using RxAndroid, Retrofit2 and Room trying to do as the flowchart below. It's quite a complex asynchronous operation and I'm struggling with it. I'm new to Rxjava and I've spent hours reading about it but it still feels very abstract to me.

I need to login into the server and get an access token before trying to fetch data from the server, then log out after I've received a response. So I need to chain the operations somehow and use the result from the previous request, but I also need to be able to handle any errors in the chain. Not sure how to handle chaining in RXjava, I've read some people suggest flatMap, but I'm not trying to combine any data.

I'm trying to follow a MVC pattern. I have one class for API calls and one class for handling the database.

Flowchart:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/MCqnUB2.png]

Comment: tell us more about the architecture pattern you are following.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Http **Authenticator or Interceptor** to do login call before every API call.